# What does CONFIG_IA32_AOUT do actually?

Tags: linux, kernel, executable

I'm running a 64bit kernel, already have `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION` set, so do I still need `CONFIG_IA32_AOUT` enabled?

From the help in `menuconfig`, I don't quite get it.

Comment: I *guess* the first one let's you run 32-bit [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binaries; the second one adds support for (older) [`a.out`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) executables. Both are [executable file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats).

Comment: Linux used `a.out` until libc4. With libc5 (around 1996?), Linux moved to ELF. So unless you want to run some binaries from the mid-nineties, you are safe without a.out support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Short answer:*

If your system is a normal desktop/laptop and you don't run any really archaic software, you should be safe to disable `CONFIG_IA32_AOUT`. Keep `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`, as chances are that some of your binaries are still 32-bit.

---

*Explanation:*

There are two issues involved here: **executable file formats** and **executing 32-bit code on a 64-bit system**.

- You can [read about file formats on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) and [have a look at their comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats), but the most important information for you is that ***ELF*** is the current standard and ***a.out*** is its predecessor. It is very unlikely that you'll find any recent program in a form of an *a.out* binary (don't mistake file format with the *default output name* that compilers give to binaries - the latter typically is still `a.out` for historical reasons, in spite of the binaries being in *ELF* format).
- If you have a 64-bit system, chances are that some of your programs are still 32-bit. This is **much** more probable than coming across an *a.out* binary.

To make it clear: binaries in both *ELF* and *a.out* format can be both 32- and 64-bit. These distinctions are separate (as you can see from [the comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats)).